# Find $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x - \sqrt{3 x - 2}}{(x^2 - 4)}$

Tags: analysis, limits

Can you help me with this limit?
What do I have to do ?
I tried to multiply by the conjugate expression but it didn't work
$$
\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x - \sqrt{3 x - 2}}{(x^2 - 4)}.
$$
Thanks

Comment: Multiplying top and bottom by $x+\sqrt{3x-2}$ does work.

Comment: I formatted your question. Make sure I've done it correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: After multiplying by the conjugate note that $x^2-(3x-2)=x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$.